# Bash script throws error "read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: linux, bash

My Script throws the error `read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable` the second time user input ( Unix Username ) is expected.

I suspect this has something to do with the first background process (linux_fetch &) going wrong.

How do I work around this so that the user prompt ( Unix Username ) post the background process  does not get affected.

Here is short snippet of the script.

```
if [ -r $linux_host_list ]
then
    echo
    read -p 'Linux Username:' LUSERNAME
    read -p 'Linux Password:' LPASS
    linux_fetch &
    clear screen
else
    echo "No Linux Servers found"
fi

if [ -r $unix_host_list ]
then
    echo
    read -p 'Unix Username:' UNIXUNAME
    read -p 'Unix Password:' UPASS
    unix_fetch &
    clear screen
else
    echo "No Unix Servers found."
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple redirection of error to /dev/null did the trick for me.

```
linux_fetch 2> /dev/null &
unix_fetch 2> /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll bet that the `unix_fetch` process is closing or doing something else insane with stdin.  Try running `unix_fetch` with `</dev/null`, so that it's stdin is redirected away to somewhere it can't do any damage.

Comment: I still keep getting the error once in while,especially if I try to provide user input fast

Comment: I just tried `< /dev/null` on a BASH script which was having the same problem, and it worked beautifully! Thanks!

Can you tell me what the difference is between `myscript.sh < /dev/null` and `myscript.sh > /dev/null`?

Comment: `< /dev/null` sets stdin (where the process reads from) to null, while `> /dev/null` sets stdout (where the process writes to) to null.